# Another Partial Deceleration Exists

Tags: c#, wpf

I have actually tried to fix this.
Basically i cannot start my project anymore with the error

Error   1   Missing partial modifier on declaration of type 'SystemTools.Controls.User.SideBar'; another partial declaration of this type exists
[PathRemovedManually]obj\Debug\Controls\User\SideBar.g.cs   41  18  SystemTools

I have attempted to change the code in this file to

```
 public partial class SideBar : System.Windows.Controls.UserControl, System.Windows.Markup.IComponentConnector {
```

Howevever everytime i rebuild it reverts back to

```
 public class SideBar : System.Windows.Controls.UserControl, System.Windows.Markup.IComponentConnector {
```

I have also deleted my entire debug folder and still having issues.

Can someone give me any ideas ?

Comment: SideBar.g.cs is autogenerated dont edit that file manually. Maybe try to check your XAML declaration for SideBar control

Comment: Yep Delete the code between <Usercontrol [Stuff in here] >. Put the general crap back in there and its working. cheers

Answer (score 0):

SideBar.g.cs is autogenerated dont edit that file manually. Try to check your XAML declaration for SideBar control. And yes, as response to your comment those craps have meaning and commonly are required.